# Jenkinsfile: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to execute a shell script in the jenkinsfile to convert choice parameter into string parameter. But I'm getting syntax error not sure what is the issue. tried suggested solution no luck.

```
    choice(
        name: 'IDS_ENVIRONMENT_LIST',
        choices: ['8108394', '7827390', '7937032']
   )

  environment {
    EMP_ID = sh(script: """#!/bin/bash 
    echo ${params.IDS_ENVIRONMENT_LIST} | sed -e 's/[][]//g;s/'\''//g;s/,$//;s/, /,/g' """, returnStdout: true ).trim()
}
```

WorkflowScript: 103: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 103, column 43.
${params.IDS_ENVIRONMENT_LIST} | sed -e]

Comment: Try escaping the dollar sign in the sed regex?

Comment: It's easier to do it on the level of groovy.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert an array to a string then use `join` method of grrovy:

```
def ID =['sdbx-1807402234', 'devl-5187460678', 'test-891137040']
def asString = ID.join(", ")
```

With shell you can just use:

```
def ret = sh(script: "echo ${ID} | sed -e \"s/[][]//g \"\", returnStdout: true)
```

Note :
If you are using `Active choice` parameter as array then note that user can select one of the choices and in this case the `params.ID` will contain the selected value and not all values.